# Insert results of a table into stored procedure as parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a stored procedure which inserts values into a table. 
Let's say its name is `usp_InsertTableA` with parameters `@ID int` and `Name varchar(100)`.

I have a requirement to call this stored procedure multiple times from another stored procedure. I am thinking to call this stored procedure something like below

```
exp usp_InsertTableA
select ID, Name from #tempTable
```

Is this possible in SQL Server to execute this with the value of the table and send it into a stored procedure?

Comment: Why not just do the insert in the second procedure ? The entire method of thinking Microsoft encourages with everything you do in sql server is to have a set based operation. If you had 100 rows produced by a select query and you had to insert them to a table, you wouldn't call a stored procedure 100 times, you'd run a single insert that inserts all 100 rows in one go. This perhaps could take the form of a table parameter to an sp that does an insert so that you are passing and inserting 100 rows

Comment: I want to re-use once SP into another SP, so I have multiple tables which we write Insert SP for those, call those SP in into one Big SP and base on business rules.

Comment: I mean like this https://codingsight.com/passing-data-table-as-parameter-to-stored-procedures/ - not like you have it there (a procedure you'd have to call 100 times to insert 100 rows)

Comment: What you want to do is certainly possible. It requires a loop, like a cursor, to iterate over every row in your temp table. That doesn't mean that is a good idea, in fact it is a bad idea. Looping is horribly inefficient and calling the same procedure over and over and over is going to cripple your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use table type parameters to stored procedure.[image]

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_MyCustomTable] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)
GO
```

And then you stored procedure would be:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_InsertTableA]
 (
    @myCustomTable udt_MyCustomTable READONLY
 )
 AS
BEGIN
  -- Your code goes in here
END
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible in SQL Server to execute this with the value of the table and send it into a stored procedure?

No, not with the stored procedure you have there. There are ugly hacks that could make it happen, but it's not how you're supposed to do things in T-SQL. Everything you do in SQL Server is supposed to be optimized to work on a set of rows, not a single row / row by row

In practice what this means is, if you have a query like this that produces 100 rows:

```
select ID, Name from #tempTable
```

You would pass those 100 rows to your insert procedure and insert them in one operation:

```
--expanding on sam's advice

--create a type 
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[udt_MyCustomTable] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)


--your insert procedure 
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_InsertTableA]
 (
    @myCustomTable udt_MyCustomTable READONLY
 )
 AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TableA(idcolumn, namecolumn)
  SELECT is, name FROM @myCustomTable
END
```

Now in your main sp that wants to insert 100 rows:

```
@DECLARE tmpVar udt_MyCustomTable;

--put 100 rows into table variable
INSERT INTO tmpVar(id,name)
select ID, Name from #tempTable

--pass 100 rows in variable to SP to insert all at once
EXECUTE usp_InsertTableA tmpVar
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  DECLARE @ID INT, @Name VARCHAR(255)
  SELECT @ID = ID, @Name=Name FROM #tempTable -- assumes one record in the table.
  EXEC dbo.usp_insertdata @id, @Name
```

Comment: Of course there is more than 1 row in the temp table. Why would they create a temp table with a single row? And why would they ask the question about needing this to work for multiple rows if there was only one?

Comment: Seam Lange: How do you know there is more than one row in the temp table from the question?

Comment: How could you possibly read this question and think it was only a single row? They clearly and directly asked how they call the procedure for each row in the temp table.